# docker-compose read-only bind volumes merge

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Currently I'm trying to mount two folders (`./app` + `./test/public`) and one file (`./test/test.py`) into a shared folder in the container (type: bind), so I always have the current code in the container without restarting. The problem is that the content in `/test` is also mounted to `/app` in the host system. Can this be avoided?

Here is my example file:

```
volumes:
  - "./app:/app"

  - "./test/public:/app/test/public"
  - "./test/test.py:/app/test.py"
```

I've searched the ninternet for about an hour now and read the docker-compose documentation, but i coudn't figure out how to solve this problem..

Hope you can help :)

edit: after docker-compose up the `./app` on the host machine contains 
`./app/test/public` and `./app/test.py` too; So i simply want to mount and merge these folders without changing the host files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid this behavior: Docker needs to create filesystem entries to which it can attach the bind mounts for your `test/...` mounts.  If you're bind-mounting a file, a file must exist at the target location first; similarly for a directory.

That means that before performing your bind mounts, Docker first creates a new (empty) file or directory to provide the target for the mount. This is what you see inside your `app` directory.

Your options are either (a) just live with it, or (b) restructure your project so that you don't need to bind mount things into an existing bind mount.